Revit Design Automation task much slower than the same task run locally
I implemented a task to export PDFs from selected viewsets in Revit using Design Automation. It works very well, but when a view includes shadows or gradients, the export slows down significantly. For example, exporting a view with shadows locally takes 2 minutes, while the same view takes 40 minutes on the Design Automation engine.
This issue might be related to hardware acceleration. When I disable hardware acceleration in my local Revit, the export process also takes around 30 minutes. Could this be because there are no GPUs on the Design Automation machines? Is there a workaround for this? Exporting 100 views would require a significant amount of processing time on DA.
Here is the code that I use for the pdf export.
private void ExportToPdf(Document doc, List<ViewSheetSet> viewSets, string pdfExportOptionName)
{
    FilteredElementCollector collectorPDFOptions = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
    IList<TableCellCombinedParameterData> namingRule = new List<TableCellCombinedParameterData>();

    var views = GetViewsOfViewSets(viewSets);
    if (views == null || views.Count == 0) return;

    ExportPDFSettings optsDoc = null;

    try
    {
        optsDoc = collectorPDFOptions.OfClass(typeof(ExportPDFSettings)).SingleOrDefault(
              settings => settings.Name.Equals(pdfExportOptionName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) as ExportPDFSettings;

        namingRule = optsDoc?.GetOptions()?.GetNamingRule();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

    }
    if (optsDoc == null) return;


    var exportFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\exportedDwgs\\pdf";
    if (!Directory.Exists(exportFolder))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(exportFolder);

    
        PDFExportOptions opts = null;
        opts = optsDoc.GetOptions();

        opts.Combine = false;

        foreach (var view in views)
        {
            try
            {


                var exported = doc.Export(exportFolder, new List<ElementId> { view.Id }, opts);

                if (!exported)
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed PDF Export: " + view.Name);
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exported pdf view " + view.Name);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }       
}

        
public static List<View> GetViewsOfViewSets(List<ViewSheetSet> viewSets)
{
    List<View> list = new List<View>();
    foreach (ViewSheetSet vs in viewSets)
    {
        foreach (View view in vs.Views)
            list.Add(view);
    }

    return list;
}

